# Lulzbot Taz Pro E2 Not Lowering Into Position

Tags: lulzbot

I just bought a new Lulzbot Taz Pro which has dual extrusion. The second extruder will not move when it is about to print so it is extruding filament in above the print bed.

When the print switches from the first extruder to the second extruder it does not move down, so when it begins to print the filament just dangles from the extruder and ends up clumping together and not sticking to the bed.

I've tried manually adjusting the heights of the extruders up and down but the second extruder will not move. I am not sure if this is a defect with the machine or if the was something i did wrong during the set up.

Comment: Hi Michael, I'm not sure what exactly your question is. See questions like https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/4329/print-quality-z-wobble-issue as a good example also this guide here will help as well https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: A good example of a question that might be better formatted, How do I test if an extruder is working, and include photos

Comment: Please add by [edit] of your question how you slice your model. The printer requires a change script of the extruder, maybe that is missing? Also, for such an expensive printer it is perfectly fine to call the manufacturer for some support, if it is defective, they will replace it.

Comment: Just looked up the Lulzbot Taz Pro - Looks like the dual extruders are possibly servo-controlled as far as position goes. Instead of being aligned side by side like normal dual setups, when you switch extruders from `E0` to `E1`, `E0` will lift away from the print and E1 will lower towards it.
I'm not finding much information about how this process actually works, chances are there's some custom slicer G-code that needs to be handled, or possibly OP needs to run some of the on-board autocalibration routines.

Comment: @Nach0s, it's T0 and T1 for tool swapping. The E argument is feedrate/extrusion.

Comment: To isolate whether it's a hardware fault -- does E2 come into position when you're switching extruders in the load filament LCD menu? (It should). Frankly, this is a problem where my first point of call would be Lulzbot's phone support; they're very readily available (and have weekend hours).

Comment: (My guess is that you genuinely do have a warrantable hardware issue, but just to cover all bases -- would it be correct to assume you're using Ultimaker Cura LE 3.6.13, per the email they sent out to TAZ Pro owners asking folks to upgrade? If so, have you connected to the printer via serial line and allowed it to upgrade the copy of Marlin? Not that I know of any bugs in the old firmware that would cause this -- but as a matter of completeness).